# How to pass a currency formatted string from the controller to the view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a formatted string variable to which passing to a ViewData Variable.
My Controller basically looks like this:

```
if(ModelState.IsValid)
{
    string total = "$2.00";
    ViewData["totalSales"] = total;
    return View();
}
```

I have an html helper function in my view like this:

```
<%: Html.Label(ViewData["totalSales"].Tostring()) %>
```

however the asp.net mvc engine is generating this :

```
<label for="$2_00">00</label>
```

I just wanna pass the money value to the view and display it. 
It appears that the decimal is breaking the value. However there has got to be a way around this. 
Am I making a noob mistake here ?

---

Well I was able to bypass this by doing this:

```
<p><%: ViewData["totalSales"].ToString() %> </p>
```

But this does not explain why a decimal in a string is causing data loss. 
Any ideas ?

Comment: i would just like to note that I am trying to figure out why a decimal causes this break. 

if the variable total was set to equal something with no decimals this technique works fine.

Comment: @Robotshushi: did you find a solution for this??If yes plz do share...thanks..I am also having the same problem...

Comment: Html.Label has a bug specifically with decimals. Dont use it for displaying text like that. I believe i ended up using a div with a code nugget inside of it. That should work =D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Use String.Format() with currency](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/programming/format-a-string-as-currency-in-c/)

Your mistake is that the framework will automatically escape/transform special characters (such as the ".") when they're turned into HTML attributes. That's by design.

Also, why are you passing a hard coded string via ViewData? Is that computed from your models? You may not be [using Label correctly](http://forums.asp.net/t/1518978.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

pass your total variable as a decimal:

```
decimal total = 2.0;
ViewData["totalSales"] = total;
return View();
```

then in your view, render the label like this:

```
<%: Html.Label(string.Format("{0:C2}", ViewData["totalSales"])) %>
```

Comment: This still causes everything before the decimal to disappear.

Comment: Well it actually sounds like you want a textbox, not a label. You are  better off skipping the Html helper. do this instead: <label for="totalSales">Total Sales:</label><%: Html.Textbox("totalSales",string.Format("{0:C2}", ViewData["totalSales"]) %>

Comment: Nice quick try, but the usage is incorrect. http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/10/asp-net-mvc-2-strongly-typed-html-helpers.aspx  Switch to <%: Html.Label("Total Sales", string.Format("{0:C2}", ViewData["totalSales"])) %>

Comment: The parameter in Html.Label() is the expression; labels do not have values - the Html helper is just formatting the value properly for an HTML id; a period/dot . is not preferred for a html element ID

Comment: @ Visionary Software Solutions - label only takes one parameter, a string. The usage was incorrect to begin with.